# firefox css image

Tags: css, image-resizing

i have a trouble with Firefox img display.
My page contains a product description:

```
<article id="productPhoto">
    <img id="prodImg" src="prova.jpg" />
</article>
<article id="productDesc">
    <h3 id="prodName"></h3>
    <h3 id="prodDesc"></h3>
</article>
```

the css is this:

```
#productPhoto{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 81%;
    text-align: center;
}
#productPhoto img{
    height: 80%;
}
#productDesc{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
#prodName{
    font-size: xx-large;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Now, the img prova.jpg is very big (width: 2676px, height: 2068px).
With Chrome the img is resized at 80% of #productPhoto, but firefox doesn't, so if i see my page in firefox, the img is huge!!! :(
Some suggestions?

Thank you,
Luca

Comment: Using classes instead of IDs will assist in making your HTML and styling reusable.

Comment: Out of interest, what is the size of that Image? At 2676px by 2068px I imagine it's pretty huge? Maybe you should consider re-sizing it?

Comment: what is the parent node of the `#productPhoto`? i assume that `height: 81%;` won't be able to calculate since the parent element simply won't have height by that time yet

Answer (score 1):

Try setting maximums for your image:

```
#productPhoto img{
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seemed a suitable answer considering you where already dealing with percentages, rather than forcing a fixed height.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put image height in pixels :-

```
#productPhoto img{
   height:100px;
}
```

Or Andy Suggestion will also work, if you want to give in percentage.

or Else you can specify parent height in pixel for Exe:-

```
#productPhoto{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
#productPhoto img{
  height:50%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <article id="productPhoto">
    <div class"imgcontainer">
    <img id="prodImg" src="prova.jpg" />
    </div>
    </article>
    <article id="productDesc">
    <h3 id="prodName"></h3>
    <h3 id="prodDesc"></h3>
    </article>
```

CSS

```
    .imgcontainer{
    witdh:80%;
    margin:0 10%;
    background-image:url(' background: url(prova.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /*for webKit*/
    -moz-background-size: cover; /*Mozilla*/
    -o-background-size: cover; /*opera*/
    background-size: cover; /*generic*/

    }
```

Comment: prefer not doing with the "background: url()", because i have to change my img dinamically! Solved with Andy/Pranav solutions!

Thank you, all, guys!!

Comment: also with backround url u waste your content as the search engines are not indexing your images.